# Fog Of War - Is looping over every tile inefficient?

Tags: java, fog-of-war

I'm trying to optimize my static FOW code for my 2D tile-based game and the bottleneck seems to be in the rendering of the fog (rather than the circle drawing algorithm or other aspect of the code).

It's a fairly simple implementation - there are two steps.

First, the game renders everything normally as if there is no fog. Then after the fact, the FOW code loops over every row and every column of tiles and if the tile is "hidden" behind fog, it draws black over the tile.

Everywhere on the web I see that this is the method most used - but to me it seems like it'd be much more efficient to set all of the tiles black, and only show through the tiles which are visible.

Although this sounds logical, in my case it turned out to be not very efficient either.

The Fog grid's tile size is different than the actual game's tile size, which provides some special challenges.

Are there any better methods for generating the Fog of War?

(The game's implementation is in Java, I can provide pseudocode if you'd like.)

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I've tried 2 circle-drawing algorithms, and there was little difference in performance (the original proved a little faster).

When I moved the fog code into the level drawing loop, I saw a notable performance increase, but it isn't a lasting solution because my fog grid size is larger than my map grid size.

EDIT 2: Here's the pseudocode - I don't feel comfortable posting the real code, as it isn't mine to post.

Level.render

```
for all x
    for all y
        if {x,y} is in view of camera
            render tile

for all visible entities
    if entity is in view of camera
        render entity

call FOW.render()
```

FOW.render

```
for all x
    for all y
        if {x,y} is in view of camera
            if tile is hidden by fog
                 render fog
```

Comment: How much faster is your rendering if you do not render fog at all, i.e. everything is visible? How exactly are you doing the drawing: pixel shaders or...?

Comment: Without rendering the fog, I'm getting about 75 fps. With fog, it drops to about 30 fps. I'm literally just drawing a black square over the section of the map: `graphics.fillRect(x, y, width, height);` No fancy shaders or anything.

Comment: How are your game tiles being drawn? Is the fog being drawn in the same way? Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: @EthanWorley I've added some pseudocode, the algorithm is fairly simple.

Comment: Looking over your pseudocode, the most obvious optimization would be to perform the fog render inside the Level.render loop, however you mention that you've already tried this and dismissed it because your fog of war tiles are a different size to your world tiles. Is it possible to map the fog of war grid to, say, 4 world grid tiles? Are there differences in the way render tile and render fog operate? do they both use graphics.fillRect()?

Comment: both do use fillRect. We've reduced the code to not render the entire width and height but just the width and height of the viewport which has bought us some cycles. fillRect does seem to be the bottleneck now.

Comment: how do you decide fog levels? I think that may be the *actual* bottle neck

Comment: Are you using a spritesheet?

Comment: @ratchetfreak There are only 2 fog levels - on or off.

If you're asking how I decide if a tile is hidden or not, it's a similar implementation to this one: http://www.appsizematters.com/2010/07/how-to-implement-a-fog-of-war-part-1-chunky/

Comment: @VaughanHilts There is no sprite sheet used, but there doesn't need to be. How would that effect the FOW?

Comment: @NicholasPickering I mean do you loop over all sight entities when checking for `tile is hidden by fog` or do you cache it

Comment: @NicholasPickering Actually, if you don't use a spritesheet you have to texture swap on each draw call which is actually seriously hurting your performance...

Comment: @ratchetfreak whether the tile is hidden by fog is stored as a flag in the FOW grid. The flag is up until the circle algo determines it should go down, where it then stays down until the end of the game.

Comment: @VaughanHilts the game is ASCII-based. The use of spritesheets isn't very common here, I believe. Since the cat's out of the bag, this also explains why my game grid doesn't necessarily line up with fog grid. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roguelike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your fog of war works, either permanent or dynamic, you could:

Dynamic: Define the distance from your entity for fog to start being generated. Determine whether a tile has fog or not on the first render loop, effectively eliminating the second.

or

Permanent: Store whether a tile has fog or not on the actual tile itself and check to see if the fog has been lifted during an update loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the FOW is static. I've left an important detail out of the question however. The Fog grid's tile size is different than the actual game's tile size. This provides some complications in the solution you've provided.

Comment: @NicholasPickering if each game grid can exactly fit a set of fog tiles then you just loop over the fog tiles in the current game grid tiles